# Universal Turing Machines with Simple Encodings of Their Tape.

Tags: reference-request, turing-machines

I am seeking a small $2$-symbol Universal Turing machine $U$ such that if $T$ is a Turing machine written to the tape of $U$ somehow, and I wish for $U$ to simulate $T$ with its tape initialized to $n$, then there is some easily computable way of writing $n$ to the tape of $T$. The known smallest $2$-symbol UTMs seem to have obscenely complicated representations of the tape of $T$, making them impractical for my purposes. I'd like a UTM with not too many states, where how to read and write to the tape $T$ is obvious. To ask a precise question: Does there exist an explicit (so the table of states is available somewhere or easily computed) $2$-symbol $1$-tape universal Turing machine $U$ with fewer than say $100$ states, such that to simulate $T$ with tape initialized to $n$, I encode $T$ somehow on the left half of the tape of $U$, and I encode $n$ in unary or binary on the right half? If necessary, feel free to drop the assumption of a single tape, or use some other simple encoding instead of binary or unary.

Comment: For sure not an answer I dare to suggest to develop such a UTM on your own with a less _"obscenely complicated representations of the tape of $T$."_ As kind of inspiration or relaxant toy you may take a [BF interpreter running on an HP15C](https://forum.hp41.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=536#p2062) (that is a pocket calculator **not** based on von Neumann architecture). For example, this program $\text{+.[[->+>+<<]>.]}$ will produce Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I was somewhat able to develop a UTM that suited my purposes, however I am unsatisfied with its size and I feel it would be better if I had a citation for its existence.